# Android's Media Player is not adding custom Headers

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, rtsp, rtp

I'm attempting to play an RTSP stream with Android's built in `MediaPlayer` class. I have written a separate library that will correctly form the Digest authentication that my IP camera requires.

I am trying to attach my generated Authorization header with the following code:

```
private void initPlayback(){
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);

        Context context = getActivity();
        Map<String, String> headers = getRtspHeaders();
        Uri source = Uri.parse(mCameraURI);

        try {
            // Specify the IP camera's URL and auth headers.
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, source, headers);

            // Begin the process of setting up a video stream.
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

For testing purposed I've hardcoded the hashmap in the following function:

```
private Map<String, String> getRtspHeaders() {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String digestAuthValue = "Digest username=\"admin\", realm=\"d8eb97cdf7d8\", nonce=\"3583e1908677b7af62f3e295eddec2f0\", uri=\"rtsp://10.20.30.62:554/Streaming/Channels/1?transportmode=unicast&profile=Profile_1\", response=\"42682812bfaf14b5406abafa179dabf9\"";
    headers.put("Authorization", digestAuthValue);
    return headers;
}
```

Now in theory when I run:

```
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

It should send a `DESCRIBE` request with my added header in it.

`MediaPlayer` instead sends this packet (captured with Wireshark/Ettercap):

```
DESCRIBE rtsp://10.20.30.62:554/Streaming/Channels/1?transportmode=unicast&profile=Profile_1 RTSP/1.0
Accept: application/sdp
User-Agent: stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 5.1.1)
CSeq: 1
```

I have traced the function calls all the way through to the native code and still can't figure out why it's not adding this header. The values get all the way to the `nativeSetDataSource` call in the `MediaPlayer` and still look correct. As far as I know I don't have a way of putting breakpoints in the native code.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually my co-worker and I were able to dig through the Android source code long enough to find a work around, but not long enough to actually find out why the custom headers were not being added.

Specifically for `Authorization` headers you can actually pass the `MediaPlayer` a modified uri. In the case of an rtsp stream it would look like this:
`rtsp://user:password@192.168.0.3:554/stream`

When the username and password are in the uri the Android `MediaPlayer` will actually pull these out and put them in the authorization header (verified with WireShark). We were able to test this on Android 4.0 and newer, but it may be true on older releases as well.

Hopefully this will help someone else out down the road.